# System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed

Tags: ssl, xamarin, mono, restsharp, tls1.2

I try to implement a RestSharp (http://restsharp.org/) client in Xamarin. But as soon as I try to connect to the server I get the exception: `System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed`

When I check with the command `certmgr -ssl https://myservice.com/api --machine` I get the same error.

So my conclusion: Mono hasn't stored the trusted root certificates.

But when I try to import them like: `mozroots --import --machine --sync` 
It won't work, because Mac OS X Sierra won't allow access to the directory `"/usr/share/.mono"`. The script throws the error: `Error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/usr/share/.mono" is denied.` And since I am unable to store the roots for mono.

Then I tried to add a Cert Validation Callback like:

```
public static class Security {

    public static System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider aesCryptoServiceProvider = new System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider();

    public static void RegisterValidationCallBack() { 
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += CertificateValidationCallBack;
        Console.WriteLine("### registered validation callback");
    }

    private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
        Console.WriteLine("### validating: " + certificate);

        // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
        if (sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None) {
            Console.WriteLine("### no ssl policy errors");
            return true;
        }

        // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
        if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0) {
            if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null) {
                foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus) {
                    if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&
                       (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot)) {
                        // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid. 
                        Console.WriteLine("### self signed cert");
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError) {
                            // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
                            // so the method returns false.
                            Console.WriteLine("### error in certificate chain");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are 
            // untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates. These certificates are valid
            // for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
            return true;
        } else {
            // In all other cases, return false.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and installed the callback here:

```
public partial class App : Application {
    public App() {
        Security.RegisterValidationCallBack();

        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new TabbedMainPage();
    }

    protected override void OnStart() {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep() {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume() {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

But it seems the callback isn't even used for some reason... the output does not appear in the output window.

What am I missing?

Comment: @Zorq No, the answer would not help, it won't resolve the issue with root certs and my Security Class does implement the solution, but the callback won't get called as I mentioned.

Comment: Execute the mozroots command preceded with sudo, it will then get privileges to write to the .mono folder.

Comment: what version of mono is this, and what OS are you using?

Comment: @Gusman no it won't. You couldn't create the folder this way in macOS Sierra.

Comment: @knocte macOS 10.12.3 and mono-4.6.0-branch/ac9e222